# google maps api key not found (but i put)

Tags: android

The error is:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
                                                                             at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.ad.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.a.e.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(Unknown Source)
                                                                             at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.h.onTransact(SourceFile:62)
```

Show_description.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="99dp"
        android:id="@+id/scroll_desc">

        <TextView
              android:id="@+id/desc"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </ScrollView>

    <fragment//line 18 here
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scroll_desc" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

A textview insinde scrollview and a map here.

manifest:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="cursedchico.showmeevets">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ListEvents" />
        <activity android:name=".ShowEventMap" />
        <activity android:name=".AndroidDatabaseManager"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>
    </application>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="xxxxx" />

</manifest>
```

I was doing this project for weeks. Yesterday i decided to map so i changed dependency

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile project(':jsoup-1.8.3')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
```

}

Probably i wont need any location service or some others so i decided to use only maps so i added only maps as service.

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=showmeevets

here i created a new project with same name of my project in android studio and then create a new credential. Did not get the signature from my project. Can it be reason?

I just got the key from the link i just provided.

Comment: is your package name exactly same in developers console??

Answer (score 0):

You are using `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0` so 
You need to replace `com.google.android.geo.API_KEY` with `com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY`

As per your error log:

> meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xmlckquote

Answer (score 0):

Place Your `meta-data` tag inside of `<application>  </application>` tag

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="cursedchico.showmeevets">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ListEvents" />
        <activity android:name=".ShowEventMap" />
        <activity android:name=".AndroidDatabaseManager"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>

 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="xxxxx" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

Add this meta-data

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="xxxxx" />
```

Comment: is it possbile to use key without sha signature?

Comment: You have to add sha signature for showing google map, without it not possible